# fullpage.js - different slide, different arrow position?

Tags: html, css, slider, fullpage.js

I want to make a fullpage.js page and need to position the arrows differently on some of these slides (only horizontal slides in my case). Is there an easy way to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Of course. 
Just use CSS and override the following styles:

- `.fp-controlArrow`
- `.fp-controlArrow.fp-prev`
- `.fp-controlArrow.fp-next`

If you want to override a specific section, just add a sector, such as an `id` or a `class`, to the section for which you want different arrows, :

```
<div class="section" id="section3"></div>
```

And then use it in the CSS:

```
#section3 .fp-controlArrow{
    /*whatever*/
}
```

Comment: but how can I override it specifically for e.g. slide 1 and a little different for slide 2?

Comment: Just use your section or slide selectors. For example: `#section3 .fp-controlArrow`.